# desktop media query affects the mobile view

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a problem where I created the first mobile view and then want to add the desktop, iPad, etc... But when I do add a media query for the "desktop view (like I want to believe)" it affects the look for mobile view.
What can I do to make the breakpoint for the desktop view, but so it won't affect the mobile, screen width, and iPad.
*Link for the full code: https://codepen.io/schoolcoder/pen/WNEgboE

```
.split {
    display: flex;
    @media screen only and (min-width:50em) {
    }
}
```

I added a screenshot as well; the end result I want and what I get when I add the code.
If anyone has any advice, I have tried a million combinations still isn't working... Would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The media query needs to encapsulate the rules that it applies to, not the other way around.

```
@media screen only and (min-width: 50em) {
    .split {
        display: flex;
    }
}
```